# How to run specific java file that contains Main with MVN?

Tags: java, maven, command-line

I got a project with a root folder containing pom.xml and in the same root directory is subfolder with all examples '/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/examples'.

Inside of that folder are 20 '.java' files. I want to run only example9.java from that folder.

Which MVN command should I run from command line and from which folder (e.g. from root or from subfolder one) in order to run example (and to make sure all dependencies are properly imported)?

Comment: The only one you can run is the one that contains "public static void main(String[])"

Comment: All 20 .java files contain "public static void main(String[])" .

Comment: mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="..../example9". If this works I will post it as an answer

Comment: I think this might work. I got MVN build etc. info but project failed (complaining something about exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli)). Not sure if is a problem with a project or MVN need to specify java version 1.8 somehow..

Comment: you need the dependency. Check: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Maven_Tutorial/2030__Maven_Run_Java_Main.htm

Comment: Is it this part?  
With runtime dependencies in the CLASSPATH:

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.java2s.ide.App" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime`

What exactly should I run.. still confused..

Comment: Post your pom. I may be able to reproduce it here later

Comment: Here is what I am trying: 1) Download Binaries from here: http://apache.spinellicreations.com//ignite/2.0.0/apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin.zip . 2) Unzip and run this particular java file (pom file is in the 'examples' folder): `/apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryExample.java`
What would be MVN command (from command line) and from which folder path to run in order to be successful?

Answer (score 2):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>stack</groupId>
  <artifactId>overflow</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>maven</executable>
          <!-- optional -->
          <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-X</argument>
            <argument>myproject:dist</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This pom.

```
package stack.overflow;

public class Main1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main1");
    }

}

package stack.overflow;

public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main2");
    }

}
```

And this two classes under the standard dir structure (you can use eclipse to create a maven project with no archetype)

And this command, from the dir where the pom.xml is

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="stack.overflow.Main2"
```

will do the trick for you

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

You would need to run mvn compile first

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command in your command prompt

```
mvn -Dtest=example9 test
```

**example9** is the java file name which you want to excutee